# Flutter Image fade out at bottom (Gradient)

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to make an Image fade out towards the bottom? So the Image has transperency 0 at the bottom.

I need the Image to be transparent, I can't use a Stack and overlay the Image at the bottom with a Color, because I don't know whats underneath the Image.

This is my Image

```
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(1), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    routine.thumbnail
                  )
                )
              ),
            )
```

I can't do this:

```
        background: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,                        
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    routine.thumbnail,
                  )
                )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 1000,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                  end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.transparent,
                    someColor // I don't know what Color this will be, so I can't use this
                  ]
                )
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! Thanks a lot. Wanna write it as a comment, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

you need a `ShaderMask`, something like this:

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (rect) {
    return LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
    ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
  },
  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/chrome.png',
    height: 400,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
),
```

here `shaderCallback` is used for returning a linear gradient that is used as a mask and with `BlendMode.dstIn` blend mode fades out your image from the top to the bottom

Comment: Is there a way to use `ShaderMask` with `image` which is a `DecorationImage` of container `BoxDecoration`?

Comment: @MehulPrajapati yes, it is: `Container` is a normal `Widget`, so you can use it too

Comment: how can i achieve the same effect but with blur?

Comment: Hello, Ibrahim yes you can use it, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885475/4300071.

Comment: How can I use this with `SliverList`?

Answer (score 8):

Not directly connected to the question but you might come across this when you just want to fade out a color in a container.
Then you can use `Container` `foregroundDecoration` for this:

```dart
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
          Colors.black,
          Colors.transparent,
              ],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0, 0.5],
    ),
  ),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Result:

[image: gradient example]