# Perfectly blend image with color of container

Tags: android, image, flutter, containers

[image: This is what i get as my output]

What i want to do is perfectly have a small gradient so that the image perfectly blends with the container below it

I tried to add an gradient to the image with the color of the container and it worked to certain extent. But the fact that the container is present is pretty visible and doesn't blend perfectly

This is my code of the carousal slider with the overlay color attached to it

```
Widget image_carousal = new Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
  child: new Carousel(
    boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
    images: [
      AssetImage('assets/images/679554.jpg'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/img.jpg'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/sekiro-shadows-die-twice-2019-4k-5b.jpg'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/tom-clancys-ghost-recon-breakpoint- 
      9m.jpg'),
    ],
    autoplay: false,
    animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    dotSize: 4.0,
    dotSpacing: 15.0,
    dotColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
    indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
    dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: false,
    moveIndicatorFromBottom: 0.0,
    noRadiusForIndicator: true,
    overlayShadow: true,
    overlayShadowColors: Color(0xFF232D3B),
    overlayShadowSize: 10.0,
  ),
```

This is my code of the SliverAppBAr and the SliverList with the container

```
CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: new Text("Home"),
              centerTitle: true,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              actions: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.search),
                Padding(padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),),
                Icon(Icons.notifications)
              ],
              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
                child: new ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[image_carousal],
                ),
              )),
            ),
            SliverList(
                delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate([
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 0.2,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Color(0xFF232D3B),
                  )])
            )
      ],
    )
```

I want the image to perfectly blend with the container color below. Let me know if that's possible or if this is as far as i can go. Appreciate anyone's help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106827/2252830

Comment: Still no luck. It covers the carousal too much and is too light to have the overlay effect

Comment: it covers your `Image` - if its too much then play with the `Rect`, and what about "too light"? meaning what?

Comment: The gradient. when i add the color that i want with a shady color like greyish, It covers the dot indicator as well.

Comment: as i said: you have to use `ShaderMask` that shades your `Image` only, not `Image` and "dot indicator"