# How to create a blur with a linear gradient in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradient, blur

I am trying to create a widget inside of Flutter that will act like the BackdropFilter widget and blur anything behind it. Although unlike the BackdropFilter, this blurrness should not be distributed evenly but instead progressively increase in blur linearly.

Does anyone have any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems possible now, using the new [`ImageFiltered`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html) Widget.

I found an example of the code through [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48212#issuecomment-592166594) GitHub comment:

```
Stack(
   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
   fit: StackFit.expand,
   children: <Widget>[
    Image.network(
             image,
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
             alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter),
      ImageFiltered(
               imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
               child: ShaderMask(
                 shaderCallback: (rect) {
                   return LinearGradient(
                       begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                       end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                       colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black.withOpacity(0)],
                       stops: [0.4, 0.75]).createShader(rect);
                 },
                 blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
                 child: Image.network(
                     image,
                     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                     alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter),
               )
     ),
   ])
```

Comment: Try to post the relevant part of the code example here, external links might not work any more after some time.

Comment: Thanks, although any idea how i might apply this blur over my widgets rather than an image?

Comment: @Lachlan Unfortunately I don't think it's possible using the code above. I am not sure how.

Comment: This is some great work, man. Thanks a lot for your response.