# How to blur part of a image?

Tags: flutter

I have an illustration below, let's ignore the other details and focus on the bottom of the image. It has a faint white streak that I don't know how to achieve. It can be **image blur** or it can be **color gradient**. It's great that you guys can help me create that **white blur**.

[image]

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804885/how-to-blur-bottom-half-of-the-screen-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you got the solution!

```
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            child: Image(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: AssetImage("assets/robot.jpg"),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.center,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  const Color(0x00000000),
                  const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the trick with the gradient color is so clever.