Gradient Blur Effect Dart
This time I wish to have a gradient blur effect over the limits of my ScrollingView. So, I have the blur effect at the right position, but I wish the effect grows slowly until the max blur. I don't want the gap between the non-blurred part and one blurred.

This image shows my problem. I don't want that horrible line caused by the effect. It is too evident ...
I've been looking on the internet for some solution, but none of them matches my needs. I put below the code that I'm having right now ...
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            //fancy content
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: ClipRRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 5,
                  sigmaY: 5,
                ),
                child: Container(width: width, height: height*0.15, color: Colors.transparent,)
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ); 

Thanks :)

You can use Gradients to achieve this, Linear Gradient with Shader Mask can be used to fix this. Also you can with different different Opacity Values to make blur gradually.

Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311065/how-to-create-a-blur-with-a-linear-gradient-in-flutter

@Lynxi this should be ok with an Image ... but I don't have to Blur and image, but a Widget

@Devraj do you have an example? The way you wrote is quite vague.
