# apply borderRadius to widget with ShaderMask

Tags: flutter

*I'm trying to create a nice linear gradient that adds kind of a shadow over the bottom of a card's image.*

I'd like this card to have rounded corners, but when I apply the ShaderMask, the bottom of the Linear Gradient being black it takes the whole space of the container (ie the container has rounded corner **but** the bottom, black part of the shader mask create right-angled corner).

See the image :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageName;
  final String title;

  ProfileCard({this.imageName, this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.transparent, Colors.black],
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          blendMode: BlendMode.darken,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/$imageName.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The top left and right corners are OK because the end upper part of the gradient is transparent.

note that the Stack has other children; I just removed them to make code more readable. Also I tried to wrap the stack inside a Container and apply borderRadius to this Container, but it did not work.

*How can I have both this nice gradient over the container background image and rounded corners at the same time ?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap `ShaderMask` widget with `ClipRRect` and provide the same `borderRadius` property value as you passed to the `Container` that holds the image.
`ClipRRect` clips it's child in rounded rectangle which shows the `Container` properly in rounded corners from all sides. Sample working code below:

```
class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageName;
  final String title;

  ProfileCard({this.imageName, this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child: ShaderMask(
                shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                  return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.black
                      ]
                  ).createShader(bounds);
                },
                blendMode: BlendMode.darken,
                child: Container(
                    width: 400,
                    height: 500,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/jpg.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    )
                ))
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.